# True mental potential of an enlightened human

Tags: siddhi

I have read many articles stating that the human soul, when enlightened has many possibilities.

- What are the various realistic mental abilities, an enlightened individual has?
- Is there any mention about all the type of siddhis a normal human can attain through enlightenment?

Answer (score 7):

The question is asked by *Arjuna* in the *Bhagavad Gita*, in the following verses:

> BG 2.54:अर्जुन उवाच |
> स्थितप्रज्ञस्य का भाषा समाधिस्थस्य केशव |
> स्थितधी: किं प्रभाषेत किमासीत व्रजेत किम् ||

> Arjun said : O Keshav, what is the disposition of one who is situated in divine consciousness? How does an enlightened person talk? How does he sit? How does he walk?

*Krsna* answers:

> BG 2.55:श्रीभगवानुवाच |
> प्रजहाति यदा कामान्सर्वान्पार्थ मनोगतान् |
> आत्मन्येवात्मना तुष्ट: स्थितप्रज्ञस्तदोच्यते ||

> The Supreme Lord said: O Parth, when one discards all selfish desires and cravings of the senses that torment the mind, and becomes satisfied in the realization of the self, such a person is said to be transcendentally situated.

> BG 2.58:यदा संहरते चायं कूर्मोऽङ्गानीव सर्वश: |
> इन्द्रियाणीन्द्रियार्थेभ्यस्तस्य प्रज्ञा प्रतिष्ठिता ||

> One who is able to withdraw the senses from their objects, just as a tortoise withdraws its limbs into its shell, is established in divine wisdom.

> BG 2.59: विषया विनिवर्तन्ते निराहारस्य देहिन: |
> रसवर्जं रसोऽप्यस्य परं दृष्ट्वा निवर्तते ||

> Aspirants may restrain the senses from their objects of enjoyment, but the taste for the sense objects remains. However, even this taste ceases for those who realizes the Supreme.

> BG 2.61: तानि सर्वाणि संयम्य युक्त आसीत मत्पर: |
> वशे हि यस्येन्द्रियाणि तस्य प्रज्ञा प्रतिष्ठिता ||

> They are established in perfect knowledge, who subdue their senses and keep their minds ever absorbed in me.

- Translation by [Swami Mukundananda](https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/)

There's a mention of **siddhis** attained by a person in the *19th* and *20th* sutras, in the *Siva Sutras* by *Vasugupta* of the **Trika School**.

[image]

[image]

[image]

- Excerpts from *Jaideva Singh*: **Siva Sutras: Yoga of the Supreme Reality**